# How to create node.js app with directadmin api

Tags: node.js, api, directadmin

I want create node.js app for user via API DirectAdmin. but the problem is:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException #403​
Client error: `POST http://xxxxxx:2222/CMD_API_APP_INSTALL` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
error=1&text=You%20cannot%20execute%20that%20command&details=The%20request%20you%27ve%20made%20cannot%20be%20executed%20 (truncated...)
```

1. Request POST send from user level
2. Domain is set as default
3. User is not in cagefs
4. from directadmin panel I can setup node js app without any issue. This is my code:

/

```
/ Request URL for installing the Node.js app
$url = 'http://xxxxxxxxx:2222/CMD_API_APP_INSTALL';

// Request data to install the Node.js app
$requestDataAppInstall = [
'domain' => $domain,
'app' => 'nodejs',
'type' => 'npm',
'path' => '/',
'version' => '14.20.1', // Specify the desired Node.js version
];

// HTTP request to install the Node.js app using Guzzle
$responseAppInstall = $client->post($url, [
'headers' => [
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $userAuthString, // Use the user's authentication string
],
'form_params' => $requestDataAppInstall,
]);

// Process the response as needed
$responseBodyAppInstall = (string) $responseAppInstall->getBody();
```

For the update above, in the same way I can create user, extra domain, email account etc, but the problem is only with node.js app

node.js app is installed via CloudLinux selector

also I try other endpoint but the same issue:

```
CMD_API_SELECT_NODEJS';
```